# UISwitch set state

Tags: ios, swift, uiswitch

I am working on an app, which has UISwitch. I want to set the switch to on/off programmatically. I tried it like so, but the switch is already turned on when `setting` is `false`... Any ideas?

```
@IBOutlet var switch: UISwitch!

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    switch = UISwitch()

    if setting == true {
       switch.setOn(true, animated: false)
    } else {
       switch.setOn(false, animated: false)
    }
}
```

the variable `setting` is not the problem.. I tested it out

Comment: From the code you posted, if `setting` is `false`, then the switch will be off. Is this not the intended functionality?

Comment: Can you specify more details ?

Comment: More details about the functionality you expected, and the actual functionality would help us greatly.

Comment: If storyboard, is the UISwitch properly connected to an IBOutlet? If done programatically, do you change the UI item directly?

Comment: sorry I meant that the switch is already turned ON when "setting" is false

Comment: Your updated code works fine, except that you are missing an ending curly brace.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it!

I just deleted the line `switch = UISwitch()` and now it works for me.